# y for x from loess, but get error with predict

Tags: r, curve-fitting, predict, loess

I have some stream cross section data. It's looks like:

```
width
 [1]  0.00  0.00  1.85  4.00  5.70  6.40  7.40  8.00  9.70 10.70 12.20 14.00 16.65 18.00 18.80 19.55 20.17
[18] 20.17

depth
 [1]  0.000  0.185  0.310  0.550  0.720  1.110  1.490  1.740  1.810  2.000  1.920  1.680  1.530  0.600
[15] -0.620 -0.760 -0.830 -0.998
```

I want to plot the points, connect the dots, then calculate y values for a standard x, like every .5 meter. 
I can make this happen using smooth.spline, but using loess actually just connects the dots.

Here is what I tried

```
plot(width, depth)
connectlines=lowess(depth[-c(1, length(depth))]~width[-c(1,length(width))], f=1/8)
lines(connectlines)
```

Because the first and last depth measurements are at a reference pin I dropped them.

Then I try to find a value before I apply it to .5m increments.

```
predict(connectlines, 4)
```

And I get the following error:

> Error in UseMethod("predict") :
>    no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list"

What's up? Seems simple. Right.
I also need to figure the length of the arc made from connecting the points if anyone has help with that as well. I've tried arclength but that doesn't work without a function. I'm using AUC for the area and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses function `loess`, not `lowess`.
According to the help page of `lowess`, section **See Also**, this function is

> **See Also**
>
> `loess`, a newer formula based version of `lowess` (with different defaults!).

The argument `f` becomes the span of the points used in the fit. I have set `span = 0.5`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(width, depth)
fit <- loess(depth ~ width, data = df1[-c(1, nrow(df1)),], span = 0.5)

new <- data.frame(width = seq(min(width), max(width), by = 0.5))
new$depth <- predict(fit, newdata = new)

plot(depth ~ width, df1)
lines(fit)
lines(depth ~ width, new, col = "blue")
```

[image]

**Data.**

```
width <- scan(text = '
0.00  0.00  1.85  4.00  5.70  6.40  7.40  8.00  9.70 
10.70 12.20 14.00 16.65 18.00 18.80 19.55 20.17 20.17')

depth <- scan(text = '
0.000  0.185  0.310  0.550  0.720  1.110  1.490  1.740  1.810  
2.000  1.920  1.680  1.530  0.600  -0.620 -0.760 -0.830 -0.998')
```

Comment: Close, but the problem I have is because this is a physical measurement, a stream bed, I can't approximate a curve of the stream bed, rather I need to connect the points. If I decrease the span I can get real close with error messages, which I can also do with a smoothing spline, but I want to just connect the points and calculate values off the lines connecting them. Then get the length of the lines added up.

Comment: I suppose I could also write up some loop function to define each line, calculate the point and length. But I assume there is an easier way.

Comment: @JoeSlow If you decrease the span, the messages are *warnings*, not errors. You can run `suppressWarnings(loess(...))` to get rid of them.

Comment: @JoeSlow The length of the predicted line is `with(new, sum(sqrt(width^2 + depth^2)))`.

Comment: OK suppressing warnings and setting spar=.125 gets the predicted points all along the line connecting the dots. I ended up adding a loop to correct the length calculation because it's change in width/depth.```for (i in 1:nrow(mydata)){
 n=(new$depth[i+1]-new$depth[i])
 new$depth2[i]=n
}

new$linelength=with(new, sum(sqrt(0.5^2 + depth2^2)))```